# vuforia image targets not recognized

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia, hololens

I'm using vuforia with hololens on unity 2017.4.3f1

I've tried the sample ImageTarget_Astronaut and it works fine.
I've added the same Image to the Target manager,
[image: this is the image defined in ImageTarget]
downloaded the database, and imported into unity project
changed the ImageTargetBehaviour Component: 
Database:from the sample VuforiaMars_Images to HOLO
ImageTarget: from Astronaut to snipFromTargetImages
[image: original component]
[image: updated component]

Added the database in the Vuforia configurations, and activated the database.
Build, and play - doesn't recognize my image.

Have I missed a step?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I've figured out.
I've seen in the log that I didn't update the license, and that solved it.